# AIY image classification project on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow

(venv) nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/tensorflow-for-poets-2$ IMAGE_SIZE=128
(venv) nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/tensorflow-for-poets-2$ ARCHITECTURE='mobilenet_0.25_128_quantized'
(venv) nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/tensorflow-for-poets-2$ ARCHITECTURE="mobilenet_0.25_128_quantized"

(venv) nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/tensorflow-for-poets-2$ python -m scripts.retrain \

## I used the code above for training a mobilenet on ubuntu and the training works fine....However, when i try testing on new images, i used the code below.

(venv) nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~/tensorflow-for-poets-2$ python -m scripts.label_image \

> ```
> --graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb  \
> --image=tf_files/Test_Images_Randomized/2018-10-23_14-24-57_696.jpg
> ```

## i got this error.

## would really appreciate anyone's help to resolve this. I have been stuck on this since last week....Thanks in advance

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 224, 224, 3) for Tensor 'import/input:0', which has shape '(1, 128, 128, 3)'

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to adjust the input image resolution in your 'label_image' script.

It might be adjusted to be using the full resolution model be default with an input size of 224x224. This should fix your dimension error. :)

Fix this:

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                            input_height=224,
                            input_width=224,
                            input_mean=0,
                            input_std=255):
```

To

```
def read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name,
                            input_height=128,
                            input_width=128,
                            input_mean=0,
                            input_std=255):
```

Comment: i tried your code and got the error below:                                                                  bash: read_tensor_from_image_file(file_name, input_height=128, input_width=128, input_mean=0, input_std=255]): command not found

Comment: Have you modified the label_image.py script provided by Tensorflow? This is the one that needs to be modified, to fix your dimension problem.

Also, in the code you pasted above, has an end square bracket "]" towards the end, without any closing brackets, delete that.